# how to define a TensorFlow graph with more than one input of different dim and combined multi different dim's layer to one layer?

Tags: tensorflow

After set each layer's name, My codes in below run well.

=================== old ===============

how to define a TensorFlow graph with more than one input of different dim?
for example, I have the Input (X1, X2, X3) with different dim(d1, d2, d3). 
how to define a  multi-input layer combined with different size's hidden-1 layer, and then combine the three hidden-1 layer to hidden-2 layer, then with a output layer ?
Thanks for all!
I tryed some code like this:

```py
model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):    
    input_layers = [tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features, feature_columns=params["feature_columns"][i]) for i, fi in enumerate(FEA_DIM)]
    hidden1 = [tf.layers.dense(input_layers[i], H1_DIM[i], tf.nn.selu) for i, _ in enumerate(FEA_DIM)]
    hidden1_c = tf.concat(hidden1, -1, "concat")
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense( inputs=hidden1_c, units=32, activation=tf.nn.selu, )
    predictions = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden2, units=NCLASS, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    labels = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels, NCLASS)
    loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(labels, predictions)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize( loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec( mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

But it doesn't work. The accuracy is not changing at training time.
The tensorboard's model graph is (the dense_xx is the hidden1's tensors):
[image]

Comment: You have 16 different features?

Comment: The most likely reason is a too large learning rate. You should start with the default `1e-3` if you like `AdamOptimizer`.

Comment: My data have 17 different dense  feature(17 slot, from 0 to 16). I  tryed  lr=0.0025 of Adam, but accuracy still unchange.   I wonder why the model graph  of the concat is series connected of 17 feature slots, but not parallel connected.   Hope you  some  advices. Thanks!
 @SiyuanRen

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem lies in these lines

```
predictions = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden2, units=NCLASS, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
labels = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels, NCLASS)
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(labels, predictions)
```

First, since you have multiple classes, you should use `softmax_cross_entropy`, or better, `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` to dispense with the one-hot encoding.

Second, the input to `softmax_cross_entropy` or `sigmoid_cross_entropy` should be unnormalized scores, so `activation=tf.nn.softmax` is wrong. All deep learning frameworks combine the softmax/sigmoid with cross entropy in one step because the combined operation has better performance and numeric stability, so you should not calculate the softmax yourself first.

Third, your learning rate is too high. Even 0.0025 is, under most circumstances, still too high. You should start with 0.001 and then tune it up and down from there.

Finally, I don't understand why you first `dense` then `concat`. Why not just concatenate all the features and then transform together?

Comment: Thanks for you advices! My task's NCLASS=2, that is a binary classification probleb. My input features were come from different sources, and have different scalar(or distribution). So I hope do the in-source compution first and then concate the after active's output.

Answer (score 0):

for how to concat the layers, give my complete running code for examples:

```
input_layers = [tf.feature_column.input_layer(features=features, feature_columns=params["feature_columns"][i]) for i, fi in enumerate(FEA_DIM)]
hidden1 = [tf.layers.dense(input_layers[i], H1_DIM[i], tf.nn.selu, name="h_1_%s" % i,
            kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l1_l2_regularizer(scale_l1=1e-3, scale_l2=1e-2), kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(H1_DIM[i]+FEA_DIM[i]))
            ) for i, _ in enumerate(FEA_DIM)]
hidden1_c = tf.concat(hidden1, -1, "concat")
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden1_c, units=128, activation=tf.nn.selu, name="h_2",
        kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=1e-2), kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(128+H1_DIM[i])))
predictions = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden2, units=NCLASS, activation=None, kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=1e-2), kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1), name="output")
```